# What about humans would scare aliens?

Tags: aliens, interspecies-relations

The following is the last transmission form a scouting party to the third planet in the sol system.

"We have only seconds to report, you have to warn the rest of the Gravtroc empire the natives of this planet they call themselves humans they ...[static transmission lost]"

Normally we are scared of aliens, but what about us might scare them.  **How might we feature in an alien's alien movie?**

The aliens could be what ever type you prefer.
Responses can be based on modern humanity or any point in human history.

The best answers would be for a type of alien that we most fear that has the most fear of us.

Comment: The answer is 100% dependent on your aliens and what they are scared of.  That which frightens us the most (nuclear war, terrorists, spiders) does not necessarily frighten them.  An alien species which has no way to detect vibrations in the air might be less frightened of our ability to make war than our terrifying ability to sense where they are in a room, even when the lights are off!

Comment: I suggest googling 'Earth is space Australia.' There are a slew of (sometimes very funny) posts and short stories about this topic, amongst other reasons aliens might think Earth is... dangerous.

Comment: This question is pretty broad, mate.  Also it seems to me like any answers would be completely opinion based.

Comment: When I was in primary school I read a short novel about a scary "alien" with pale skin, only two arms and one head, who squealed orribly when hit by a laser... anything which is other than "our" aspect is scary.

Comment: Humanity is a species that decided that the best response to having enough nuclear weapons to kill millions of them was to build enough nuclear weapons to kill billions of them. That's pretty scary.

Comment: Edited question to make it less opinion based give me the scariest aliens that fear humans the most

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OcPqk-O-fD4. We're totally immune to any form of the halting problem attack.....

Answer (score 5):

Just a few reasons to start off with:

1: We can get along under the freezing point of water anywhere up to halfway to the boiling point of water. While naked.

2: When you cut us, it regenerates.

3: We can remain functional even after losing a limb. Or three. Or four. Some members of human society are still influential even though they're almost completely paralysed.

4: We have at least 5 senses, not counting internalised senses like balance and proprioception

5: We think it's a good idea to go to war over abstract concepts. Seriously. What species will go fight for peace?

6: Sometimes, in times of stress, we can display extraordinary feats of strength, endurance or outright inability to feel pain. Some humans hack off their own limbs in order to survive, while fully conscious and cognisant of what they're doing.

7: Some of us just go ahead and permanently punch holes through our bodies anyway, for decoration.

8: It isn't uncommon for us to strap ourselves into metal boxes filled with explosive material and make them go very fast around tight tracks. This is considered 'fun'

9: We not only farm animals, we've optimised the process for meat production to the point where we give life to, grow and kill billions of life forms a year. Much of this meat goes to waste.

10: One of us came up with the concept of Mutually Assured Destruction. We gave them a prize. For promoting Peace.

There are more, but hopefully this list gives some flavour of how bat-bleep terrifying humanity is.

Comment: Building on #9, we also domesticate animals. We took wolves and beat them into submission until, over the course of generations, they became dogs. And rather than stopping at having trained them to serve as guardians and hunting companions, we bred them until they became poodles, just so we could keep them around to look at and say, "aww, how cute".

Comment: @BenS. Actually, the widely accepted theory (at least last I heard) is that wolves domesticated themselves. Humans provided the incentive (scrap heaps of easily accessible food, for example), but wolves did the majority of the work of actual domestication. Training is a different issue, but that works on the scale of individuals, not species.

Answer (score 2):

... paranoid?

A gigantic spaceship appeared few days after release of "Independence Day".

They were greeted by a salvo of nuclear weapons, but they hadn't any "force shield".